# wkhtmltopdf specifying authorization header

Tags: pdf, command-line, http-headers, wkhtmltopdf

Need to send a header to get past security to take a screenshot of a page using wkhtmltopdf. I need to send a header the looks like:

```
"Authorization=Basic " + some base 64 set of characters.
```

for some reason nothing I do works... I've tried

```
--custom-header "Authorization" "Basic ectectect"
--custom-header "Authorization"="Basic ectectect"
--custom-header "Authorization=Basic ectectect"
```

Some help would be appreciated... the documentation is not so good.

Comment: Hi @user3084366. Did you get this issue resolved by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

So I know this question is old, but I just had this problem and of the 2-3 mentions of it anywhere on the web, no answers were found. In my case, I was calling a page that makes an ajax request to load data. Without using `--custom-header-propagation`, the authorization header I specified wasn't being propagated to this subsequent ajax request, which is why it appeared to fail with an authorization error.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Authorization "Basic tokenHere"
```